# find out when user leaves a page in django

Tags: python, jquery, django, ajax, django-views

I have an ajax function that sends requests to a Django view every second:

```js
function get_updates() {
    $.ajax({
        url: full_path,
        type: 'GET',
        data: {latest_pk: latest_pk},

        success: function(json) {
            ...
        },

        complete: function(data) {
            setTimeout(get_updates, 1000);
        }
    });
}

get_updates();
```

get method of the view is like this:

```py
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.GET:
        # If there are GET parameters, use them to return updates.
        response = self.get_updates(request.GET.get("latest_pk"))
        return JsonResponse(response)
    else:
        # Otherwise if the url is simply requested,
        # return the rendered chat page.
        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

How can I execute some code in Django, after requests stopped being sent? I need to save the time of the last request.

Comment: I think you shoud use redis as db, that store online users for a while. And update  "online_state" in redis and "last_action_time" in database by some actions like "send_message". So, when "online_state" expired, you show description about "last_action_time".

Comment: @lmaxyz Is there a way to do the same just in django? define something that expires if it's not renewed?

Comment: @aaroon You can run thread, that will live about 5 seconds, and after that if time is not updated it will save last action time in db. But I think all of like this things are worst than solution with redis. And if you asking about built-in features in django, I don't know such.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in javascript there is event called `."beforeunload"`.
This is just an idea how you can achieve it

```
<script>
window.addEventListener("beforeunload",function(){
      $.ajax({
        url: full_path,
        type: 'GET',
        data: {latest_pk: latest_pk},

        success: function(json) {
            // add your other logic here
        }
    });
  


});
</script>
```

Comment: I need the ajax function, It's not just for this. I have to send requests by second anyway so I thought I can use it to find out when user was receiving updates. And does this method works for cases where internet is disconnected or it's just for exiting the page?

Comment: @aaronn this is an event fire when the user is ready to leave a page.example you are inside a chat you start writing a message and you leave the page you can call `.beforeunload event` to store the message so that when the user comes back to that chat you can show him the message he started to write.